# UIRefreshControl() in iOS 11 Glitchy effect

Tags: swift, ios11, xcode9, uirefreshcontrol

Every time I pull to refresh the TableView, the UIRefreshControl appears to be glitchy. Below is the code I am using. Any Ideas?

In AppDelegate:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.red
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
```

In UITableViewController:

```
self.tableView.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
  self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
} else {
  // Fallback on earlier versions
}

self.tableView.refreshControl = refreshCont
```

Comment: if we had the same issue, I fixed mine by setting self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES, don't ask me why

Comment: @hhanesand Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For me `self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES` fixed the issue.