# scroll to top of tableview and show large title iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationbar, large-title

I want to scroll to the top of my tableView and also show the `largeTitle` in the `navigationBar` when I tap on the tab in the tabbar.

Using the `scrollToRow` method does not show the largeTitle:

```
extension TableViewConstroller: UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        if tabBarController.selectedIndex == 1 {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
            tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried

```
self.tableView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(x: 0, y: -64, width: 1, height: 1), animated: true)
```

This works sometimes, but if I scroll way down the `tableView`, the `navigationBar` is still collapsed when this method scrolls up.

What can I do to mimic the behavior of the tableView's `scrollsToTop` property that does scroll to the top and shows the `largeTitle`? It animates very smoothly and always shows the large `navigationBar`.

Comment: Have you set `prefersLargeTitles` for your `navigationBar` ?

Comment: please see this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50625225/ios-11-scroll-to-top-when-using-large-titles-doesnt-work-properly

Comment: @koen yes, prefersLargeTitle is set.

Comment: @SidShehxad that question is based on a scrollView, I have a tableView

Comment: @WalterBeiter `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView` so it may well be applicable.

Comment: @koen that question's answer does not solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

I used these two methods inside the `UITabBarControllerDelegate`:
The second method searches for the first `scrollView` and then scrolls to the top on that `scrollView`. And since a `tableView` is also a `scrollView`, this approach works.

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    if tabBarController.selectedViewController == viewController {
        if let scrollView = findScrollView(in: viewController.view) {
            let desiredOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -scrollView.contentInset.top - 96 + UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height)
            scrollView.setContentOffset(desiredOffset, animated: true)
        }
    }
    return true
}

private func findScrollView(in view: UIView) -> UIScrollView? {
    if let scrollView = view as? UIScrollView {
        return scrollView
    } else {
        for subview in view.subviews {
            if let scrollView = findScrollView(in: subview) {
                return scrollView
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: 96 is the height of the large navigation bar.

Comment: I am aware of that but you should get it dynamically and not hardcode it

Comment: When and where can I get that dynamically? I need a precise moment where I can get the height of a large navigationBar. Or is there a constant somewhere in UIkit where I can read that value from?

Comment: cannot find that edit anymore, so I don't know what you wanted to change